# How to run Qt5 applications with a specific translation?

Tags: qt, internationalization, qt5, translation

I'm adding translations to a Qt5 project and I'd like to run the application with a specific translation to test it with a different language.  I already have the .ts files and generated the corresponding .qm files.  However, I found no information on how to run Qt5 applications with a specific translation.  I've found some references based on setting the `LANG` environment variable in linux but I had no success.

Does anyone know if it's possible to run a Qt5 application with a specific language? If it is, what's the best way to set which language is used by a Qt5 application?

Answer (score -1):

Add `TRANSLATIONS += lang_ua.ts` to your .pro file. Then add to your `main()`

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QTranslator translator;
translator.load("lang_ua");
a.installTranslator(&translator);
```

For changing translation load another file in `translator.load()`.
All your translations will be read with `QObject::tr()`

Comment: As I've mentioned in the question, I already have the translation working.  What I don't have is a way to test specific translations by specifing which translations should be used when the application runs.

Comment: @RAM This answer could be improved, but it's essentially correct. If you want to use a different translation, you have to install it yourself programatically. You can add your own command line switch to pass in a different locale name and use it to parameterize your translator.

Comment: @JasonHaslam the availability of the translations is not an issue, and hard-coding translator languages is simply wrong.  The standard Qt way of setting languages is to call `QTranslator::load()` with a default `QLocale` object, which sets the locale info determined from the system's locale settings at application startup. Thus, changing the system's locale settings will also determine which locale the Qt application will run, without having to hard-code anything.

Comment: @RAM I didn't say that you should hard-code the language. I said that you should add a command line switch to your app to pass in the language you want to test. Then, if the switch is given, use that language instead of the system locale when you load translations.

Comment: @JasonHaslam sorry, I failed to understand your point.  I have to agree that your proposal does solve the problem.